# pdfgrep error under cygwin

Tags: pdf, cygwin, grep

I am trying to grep over some pdf using pdfgrep which I download from here:
http://fd0.x0.to/cygwin/release/pdfgrep/

I then unzip it and put files into the cygwin corresponding folders. 
Initially I got error saying cannot find libpoppler19.dll so I downloaded it and put it under bin. Then now when I run pdfgrep I got a error I don't know how to fix:

> /usr/bin/pdfgrep.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Why I am getting a ? instead of a specific lib name ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry forget to settle this one down. I ended convert pdf into txt and using nativa grep from cygwin under windows, it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ldd /usr/bin/pdfgrep.exe` to get a list of linked libraries. Also, it sounds as if you did install manually, not via setup. There should be a setup.hint with library requirements, something like `requires: cygwin libcurl4 libexpat1 libgcrypt11`.